# Why the value in model.put is appended in URL

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring MVC Web App.  In one Controller, I used model.put method to pass some information to a jsp file.

The following is the snippet of controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login" ,  method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginPost(HttpSession session,ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "username") String username, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) throws Exception {
    User user = getUser(username, password);
    if(user !=null){
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        model.put("message","login successful  ");
        return "redirect:/index";
    }else{
        model.put("message","login failed");
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

The index.jsp and login.jsp:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<body>
<a href="/upload">Click to upload page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: cbl
  Date: 2016/1/6
  Time: 15:34
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${message}</h1>

<form method = "POST" action = "/login">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name = "username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password"type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The ${message} is extected to be display within body, however, it is appended after URl:`http://localhost:8000/login?message=login+failed` and `http://localhost:8000/index?message=login+successful++`

Any response is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning a redirect, a new GET request is created under the covers, that is why is getting attached to the url.

If you want to keep the data in the **model** only, you can use the flash scope with `RedirectAttributes`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login" ,  method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginPost(HttpSession session,
                        RedirectAttributes ra,
                        @RequestParam(value = "username") String username, 
                        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) throws Exception {
    User user = getUser(username, password);
    if(user !=null){
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("message","login successful  ");
        return "redirect:/index";
    }else{
        ra.addFlashAttribute("message","login failed");
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```